# machine learning for computer virus detection

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

I search any dataset(s) which use to train machine detect computer virus.
Has anybody example data  for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft provides a dataset for malware prediction on Kaggle. The dataset and more information can be found at 
https://www.kaggle.com/c/microsoft-malware-prediction/data